# isolated storage does not store data when the app exits

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application in Windows Phone 8 
and i need some small data to store (Highscore in my case)

The app is about a math game which has a timer 
When i finish the game , the highscore updates , and even if i navigate back and re-navigate to the page the highscore fields still shows the saved highscore  , which is great

The problem is when i exit the app and re-open it , the highscore resets ..
i dont know why

My code:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings highScoreSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


  public void TimeLeftTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            prog1.Value-=10;
              //GAME ENDS
            if (prog1.Value == 0)
            {
                //If there is already a highscore saved 
                if(highScoreSettings.Contains("highscore"))
                if (Score > Convert.ToInt32(highScoreValue.Text))
                { 

                    highScoreSettings.Remove("highscore"); // remove highscore
                    highScoreSettings.Add("highscore", Score.ToString()); // update highscore
                    highScoreValue.Text = highScoreSettings["highscore"].ToString(); 
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Time is out");
                TimeLeft.Stop();
                prog1.Value = 100;
                return;
            }


// LOAD DATA
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("highscore"))
            highScoreValue.Text = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["highscore"] as string;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you call "Save" on your settings before you exit (or when for instance leaving the settings page):

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

You could just call it every time you change a setting, but it's recommended to not doing it too often (so if you do a group of changes, don't call save until the end).

Answer (score 2):

Use Save method when you are updating your setting:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings highScoreSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  public void TimeLeftTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            prog1.Value-=10;
              //GAME ENDS
            if (prog1.Value == 0)
            {
                //If there is already a highscore saved 
                if(highScoreSettings.Contains("highscore"))
                if (Score > Convert.ToInt32(highScoreValue.Text))
                { 

                    highScoreSettings.Remove("highscore"); // remove highscore
                    highScoreSettings.Add("highscore", Score.ToString()); 
                    highScoreSettings.Save();
                    highScoreValue.Text = highScoreSettings["highscore"].ToString(); 
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Time is out");
                TimeLeft.Stop();
                prog1.Value = 100;
                return;
            }
```